# Eagerload 3 models or access between them

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 models, Subforum, Topic and post. Is it possible to Eagerload all 3?

```
class Subforum extends Model
{
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Topic')->orderBy('sticky', 'desc')->latest("updated_at");
    }
}

class Topic extends Model
{

    public function subforum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subforum');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do something in the likes of

```
Subforum::with('topics')->with('posts')->limit(1)->get();
```

Or how to find what Subforum is Post a part of, through Topic, like

```
$post->topic()->subforum()
```

or

```
$post->subforum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, its called Nested Eager Loading:

```
Subforum::with('topics.posts')->first();
```

If you have a Post instance already you can walk the relationship to the Subforum, assuming all these relationships exist in the database:

```
$post->topic->subform;
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Jeez, that was deadass simple, don't know how I missed it in the Docs, thank you!